# How ROS2 communication is done between two nodes over DDS?

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a newbie in the ROS2 paradigm. I have Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS2 Foxy installed on it. I am able to communicate among nodes via publishing/subscribing topics and services. I have read the documentation about default DDS in ROS2. I have also read about, how to create a [fast DDS](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/v2.3.0/fastdds/getting_started/simple_app/simple_app.html) publisher and subscriber, as well as [the topic name mapping](http://design.ros2.org/articles/topic_and_service_names.html#mapping-of-ros-2-topic-and-service-names-to-dds-concepts) between ROS2 and DDS.

But I am still unable to understand how can I communicate between two nodes over DDS? Do I need a [discovery server](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Discovery-Server/Discovery-Server.html)?

What steps should I follow to communicate via a topic between two nodes?

**Confusions:**

1. As DDS follows idl format for
   messages, how msg and srv files will
   be translated to dds?
2. There is also an integer domain_value to set up
   the availability among publishers
   and subscribers. How can I set
   domain values?
3. Will publishing and subscribing to DDS topics follow the same procedure as ROS2 topics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392068/how-ros2-communication-is-done-between-two-nodes-over-dds?/) by [sumit.paul](https://answers.ros.org/users/90791/sumit.paul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A newbee like me might find this answer helpful.

After some debugging I have figured out the way to communicate different nodes over dds.

```
RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp ROS_DOMAIN_ID=<id> ros2 run <package> <application>
```

This will run the ROS2 node on the fastrtps DDS. To establish pub/sub communication between two nodes we have to use the same ROS_DOMAIN_ID. As fastrtps is the default dds middleware for ROS2 so we do not have to install it seperately. If anyone has to use other dds middleware he/she has to download the desired dds middleware and replace it in the  `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=<desired_dds>`

If the ROS2 nodes are in different DOMAIN, then **Integration-service** is there to save us. Please check this links. [ROS2-FASTDDS](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/ros2/ros2.html), [Integration-Service](https://integration-service.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/installation_manual/installation.html),  [ROS2-Different-Domain-Communication](https://integration-service.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/examples/same_protocol/ros2_change_domain.html)

The transformation of ROS2 topic and DDS idl are handled by the integration-service. [This example](https://github.com/eProsima/Integration-Service/blob/main/examples/basic/ros2_server__addtwoints.yaml#L17) can be a good starting point.

If anyone has to compile their own ROS2 msg/service/interfaces and generate mix files to use in the integration-service please check this, [ROS2-System-handle.](https://github.com/eProsima/ros2-SH)

---

Originally posted by [sumit.paul](https://answers.ros.org/users/90791/sumit.paul/) with karma: 36 on 2021-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1